# Can't actually turn built-in monitor off

Tags: display, settings

is this a known bug? the button in the GUI display settings that you use to turn the monitors off is non-functional for me.

Comment: Same problem here. I have a lenovo laptop and it only turn off my built-in monitor via a hardware switch (didn't happen on windows)